# Reactive Kafka Receiver poll new records even old ones are not ack

Tags: spring-kafka, project-reactor, reactor

I am trying to use Reactive Kafka Receiver in order to process Kafka messages. I expected that consumer will give me new message only in case the last one I polled has been acknowledged. However, even if I do not run ack I get new records. Is it a desired behaviour or am I missing some configs?

```
void consumeMessages() {
    kafkaConsumer(() -> true).subscribe();
}

Flux<Void> kafkaConsumer(BooleanSupplier repeatCondition) {
    return reactiveConsumer
        .receive()
        .doOnError(error -> log.warn("Received error when get kafka message", error))
        .doOnNext(receivedRecord -> log.debug("Received event {}", receivedRecord.value()))
        .flatMap(this::handleReceivedRecord)
        .onErrorResume(error -> Flux.empty())
        .repeat(repeatCondition);
}


Flux<Void> handleReceivedRecord(ReceiverRecord<String, CustomEvent> receivedRecord) {
    return Mono.just(receivedRecord)
        .flatMapMany(
            record ->
                handleCustomEvent(record.value())
                    .doOnComplete(() -> {
                        log.debug("Committing offset for record: {}", record);
                        //record.receiverOffset().acknowledge();
                    })
                    .onErrorMap(error -> new ReceiverRecordException(record, error)))
        .doOnError(error -> log.error("Error when processing CustomEvent", error))
        .retryWhen(
            Retry.backoff(consumerProperties.retries(), consumerProperties.minBackOff())
                .transientErrors(true))
        .onErrorResume(
            error -> {
                ReceiverRecordException ex = (ReceiverRecordException) error.getCause();
                log.warn("Retries exhausted for " + ex.getRecord().value());
                ex.getRecord().receiverOffset().acknowledge();
                return Mono.empty();
            });
}
```

Comment: You process consumed messages concurrently. If there are no exception, kafka poll will consume from last read offset. Change flatMap to concatMap for sequential process. Also you can set max.poll.records/interval etc to achieve the requiered behaviour.

Comment: Does it mean that if I poll 500 messages (starting from offset 0, ending at 500) and I will first process message with 500 offset and commit after the application crash I will lost 499 messages (because offset is commited already at 500)?

Comment: If you commit any offset, all message before it will count as a processed message in that consumer group.

Comment: So does it mean using flatMap with commit is very dangerous (in case of e.g. crash)?

Comment: Yes, it can happen you ack a message while another behind failed to process